# Приложение PHPStorm неожиданно завершило работу (Mac OS Ventura 13.3.1)

Tags: phpstorm

При запуске PhpStorm 2022.3.2 стал выдавать ошибку: Приложение неожиданно завершило работу. Также не запускается Android Studio с аналогичной ошибкой.

Из последнего что делал это удалил IDE Eclipse.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Как решали?

[Лог ошибки прилагаю.](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/P5it/Ne6xrFtzb)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]